# Reversing the compound interest formula

Tags: compound-interest

The compound interest formula is

$$
A =P( 1+r ) ^{n}
$$

If I want to find $n$ it seems logical to that I just solve for it using the logarithm base (1+r), like so:

First divide by $P$:

$$
\dfrac{A}{P} = ( 1+r) ^{n}
$$

and then:

$$
log_{(1+r)}(\dfrac{A}{P}) = n
$$

which is easily solvable. However, this is wrong, apparently. It seems logical to me that you can just apply the rule that if $b^x=y$ then $log_{b}(y)=x$. Can somebody explain why this does not work? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I made a mistake - I meant "solve for $n$", not "solve for $r$", as I wrote first. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: It's not strictly wrong, but it doesn't help you solve for $r$. The only way to get $r$ from here is to ... raise both sides to the power of $r$ again. Instead of taking a logarithm, take the $n$th root instead.

Comment: ‘However, this is wrong, apparently’ - Why?

Comment: What you did is technically correct. However, what we would normally do is take $\ln$ on both sides, so you get
$$
\ln\left(\frac{A}{P}\right) = n\ln(1 + r) \implies n =\frac{ \ln\left(\frac{A}{P}\right)}{\ln(1 + r)}
$$

I don't know what you mean by "wrong" though.

Comment: You aren't wrong. The change-of-base formula $\log_b(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(b)}$ would turn your answer into the same answer in the previous comments $n=\frac{\ln(\frac{A}{P})}{\ln(1+r)}$. Many people would frown on a log with base 1+r because most calculators can only easily handle base 10 (log) or base e (ln).